# DatabaseError: Unable to open db file, but only for Django admin

Tags: database, django, django-admin, sqlite

This may be the strangest problem in my 4 years with Django.

My site is working alright locally. In production environment it also runs fine, except, when I try to access the admin site, I get a server error which is an "OperationalError: unable to open database file" in the Apache error log.

The DB file is world writable and the path in the settings are absolute. The production environment is Ubuntu Lucid / Python 2.6 / Sqlite3. I tried both with Django 1.2.4 and 1.3 beta.

The weird part is, I can `syncdb` on server. It creates the tables and the admin user. I can access the site without problem. I can run `shell` and create content within python prompt. The site is browsable. It is only when I access admin, I get this error.

I have no basis left for any reasoning. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**ps:** The error is raised at Apache level, not from Django. The Django traceback is in Apache error log, which reads `DatabaseError: unable to open database file`.

Comment: Are you sure all your models are the same version like in the database? I had a similar problem once and I didn't realized it in the beginning because I used this model very seldom on my normal page. But the admin will open all of them at once.

Comment: i couldn't find any problem with models. i can access the admin site locally anyway. also, if it was models, i would get a different error, not `cannot open database file`. so it must be something else i think. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stupid guess.

Which user is running apache?

I know it's strange that the rest of the site works, but double-check your sqlite db is reachable and read-writable from the user Apache is running as!

Comment: yes, thanks! i changed the owner group for the whole directory tree to `www-data`, which is apache, and it worked. strange that i'd already given 777 permission to the sqlite database file but it didn't work. thanks.

Comment: Happy to hear good news. Maybe the file was 777, but one (or more) directory in the path was not allowing the apache user to reach the file!

Comment: I know that is an old question but for completeness: python sqlite module requires write access to the directory containing the database file.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown www-data /var/www/yourproject/db.sqlite3
```

this will do the trick(set the user to Apache)